# Getting real time data from embedded application to webpage

Tags: webserver

I have an embedded application running on an arm board which will generate real-time information asynchronously. I need to display that asynchronous data to a web page so that the users can monitor the values in a real-time manner. To be more precise whenever a data is generated by the embedded application a web server should fetch that data and it should push the data to a Web page and the webpage should display the new value in real time.
Note: 
The embedded application is written in c.NGINX and the PHP-fpm are already running on the Arm board. Web page should support IE 11, Chrome and Mozilla browsers

it will be helpful if someone can point out a solution.